# Glass marble on a plane

Tags: geometry, spheres

There is a glass marble standing still on an absolutely smooth planar surface.
Assuming ideal conditions, the marble touches the surface on a single point O (O is a point on the plane).
We take away the marble and put it back so that it stands still on the same point O.
Is it possible to find an orientation, such that no single point on the marble surface is on the same 3d coordinates as before?

My attempt:  If we rotate the marble by half a circle, on a great circle that passes through the contact point? And this is only by intuition.

Comment: See Brouwer fixed point theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem.

Comment: What about those points on the resulting hemispheres that are the furthest from the great circle that you chose? They remain on the same $3D$ coordinates as before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible for 3-dimensional marbles.

It can be proven (see [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem)) that any re-orientation of the marble can be considered as a *single* rotation around some axis by some angle. Any point of the marble which was on the axis before the re-orientation, will be in the same place afterwards.

**More formally**: because re-orientation preserves distances, any such re-orientation of the marbe is given by an orthogonal matrix $O$ (this even include mirroring the marble). It is known that any such matrix has a real eigenvector to the eigenvalue $1$. Any point on the marble which is in the span of this eigenvector will remain fixed during the re-orientation.

Comment: He is asking for any orientation and not just one rotation through an axis. Obviously for one axis rotation its not possible!

Comment: Any reorientation in 3D is a rotation. Or do I get any other part of the question wrong?

Comment: You could rotate it twice, thrice or as many times as you like, right?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, any concatenation of rotations will give again a rotation, which has an axis.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot about that part. Thanks for clearing that!

Comment: Now from last comment, I understand! Is it some euler theorem?

Comment: @KingTut Exactly. It's [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem). Added the link to my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and replies. I just went through Euler's theorem - I did not understand much, as I am not a mathematician. Just to clarify that O is a fixed point on the plane and not on the marble, right? I don't know if this changes anything :)

Comment: @PradeepSuny If I understand your question correctly, then the point where the marble touches the plane uniquely determines it's center point. This is all the theorem assumes (that the center is the same after the re-orientation).

Comment: @M.Winter Yes the center is the same. (I guess you mean that the 3d coordinates of the center are the same).

Comment: @M.Winter: But in Euler's rotation theorem it is stated that "When a sphere is moved around its centre it is always possible to find a diameter whose direction in the displaced position is the same as in the initial position." So in essence, it is possible to find such an orientation, right? because the center remains the same and any displacement is a rotation through the center. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Samuel No, you are completely right. I hope this was what I was saying in my post. Or not? :o

Comment: Oops sorry - I didn't read carefully! I saw "this is not possible" and thought you were referring to the original question that OP posted.

Comment: @M.Winter thank you for your solution. How can one explain this in a simple way? I understand that the center remains at the same coordinates and if we take a random point on the surface, this can be displaced by a single rotation through "some" axis that passes through the center. Is there any simple proof without too much math?